# CakePHP and SVN

Tags: svn, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to collaborate with my team on SVN. I would like to know which is the best way to configure SVN ignores on Cakephp Package. I have been getting a lot of conflicts when i have tried working with it before.

I use Tortoise SVN on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using SVN with some Cake projects and usually ignore the entire `cake` folder (it's not part of the project itself and hence shouldn't be under version control), the `app/tmp` folder and for security sake the `app/config/database.php` file.

Comment: I personaly prefer to have the cake folder in the repository. Some version may contain a bug, a new one may correct it, etc. and it ensures that everybody works on the same one. Cake is a framework, but what is it if not lines of code that make your application runs, even if you didn't write them yourself ? To me an app is a whole, and I prefer to have it all at the same place.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually working with cakePHP on SVN and the only one folder we are ignoring is "tmp" in "app" folder since we are all running it in localhost and it could mess session system.

Comment: don't forget to exlude sensitive data like passwords and database.php!

Comment: +1 on Oldskool and Mark about security. Cake folder should not be necessary but take care of which version you are using (1.3 or 2.0) since conventions are different.

Comment: I need to add my cake core - due to own bugfixes. but I always add it as "external" svn rep.